# Find smallest possible array for given condition

Tags: java

I have an array say `int[] x = {1,0,0,2,0,2}`. Sum of pow(2,x[i]) of each element is `13`.
I want to find *Smallest Possible Array* which fulfills same condition (sum of square of each element should be `13`).
Please help me out.

Comment: Your sample array, the sum of the square of each element is 5 (not 13).

Comment: Please show us your attempt at this problem.

Comment: The array needn't be any larger than 13 elements, and the individual elements needn't be any larger than 3. Just start with a two element array and try every possible combination of two numbers each between 0 and 3, and if that doesn't work try a three-element array, and so on until you've tried a thirteen-element array.  Actually you won't need to try anything larger than two elements: the answer is {2,3}.

Comment: correction in my condition. really sorry for that.

Comment: condition is = Math.pow(2,1)+Math.pow(2,0)+Math.pow(2,0)+Math.pow(2,2)+Math.pow(2,0)+Math.pow(2,2) like this. so sum is 13.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez"

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @RidhdhiPatel `Math.pow(2,x)` gives you powers of 2, not squares.

Comment: @ajb yes that is why i updated condition. square is not correct word so i wrote the equation for this. sorry for inconvenience. please solve my problem. thank you.

Comment: Then please edit the question and take the word "square" out of the question.  Also, "please solve my problem" is not what we do on Stack Overflow.  We expect questioners to make an attempt to solve the problems themselves.  But I'll give you a really big hint: _binary notation_.

Comment: @ajb thank you very much for your kind support. I am new to stack overflow so I was not knowing these details. I will look for binary notation and then post here with my tried version of code. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

public void solution() {

```
    double equation = 0;
    int[] a = new int[] { 2, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3 };
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            equation = equation + Math.pow(2, a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(equation);

        int equation1 = (int) equation;
        int binaryArray[] = new int[30];
        int i = 0;
        while (equation1 > 0) {

            binaryArray[i++] = equation1 % 2;
            equation1 = equation1 / 2;

        }
        int sum = 0;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        do {
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (binaryArray[j] == 0) {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                sum = sum + (binaryArray[j] * (int) Math.pow(2, i));
                i--;
                list.add(i);
            }
        } while (i > 0);
        // shortest list
        System.out.println(list);
        // length of shortest list
        System.out.println(list.size());

    } finally {

    }

}
```